# Creating text files in every sub-directory

Tags: files, find, directory, xargs

I have a directory hierarchy named, for example, `abc` and a text file `names.txt`. I need to choose several lines from the text file and then create new files with sample text, say "Hello world", in every sub-directory of the `abc`, where every chosen line from the `names.txt` is the name for one of the new files. I have to do it in one line using `xargs` or `-exec`. I've tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
find abc -type d -exec sh -c 'grep ^'A' names.txt | xargs -I% sh -c 'echo 'Hello world' | tee {}/%'' \;
```

How to do this the right way?

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with what you need to for one directory:

```
awk '/^A/ { print "Hello world" >$0 }' names.txt
```

This would read the file called `names.txt` and write the string `Hello world` to each filename given by a complete line of input from that file, if the input line starts with a capital `A`.

With a small modification, we can get it to output to a file under a specific directory, `$dirname`:

```
awk -v dir="$dirname" '/^A/ { print "Hello world" >(dir "/" $0) }' names.txt
```

We may then use `find` to call this for each subdirectory (including the start directory):

```
find abc -type d -exec awk -v dir={} '/^A/ { print "Hello world" >(dir "/" $0) }' names.txt \;
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, `print >(expression)` appears to work.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The issue with using `-execdir` here is that the `names.txt` file has to be given with an absolute pathname. That's not difficult to organize though...

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, I thought the `names.txt` was to be found in each directory. Then that won't work. With -execdir, the command runs in the _parent_ of the file being found (hence the `-name names.txt -execdir...`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In, the parent, of course. Doh.

Comment: Note that the `dir={}` assumes a version of `find` that expands `{}` when found as part of arguments, and that directory names don't contain backslash characters.